# how to display 15 rows using switch in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, switch-statement

I am using totally 15 static rows in my UICollectionView. If I click on each item it will navigate  to the associated UIViewController. First I have used If-else but now I don’t  to use the If-else. I am using switch for that.But my doubt is for 15 rows I am writing 15 cases for that. But i want to reduce my code. Is there any logic to reduce the code.

My code in like dis

```
  switch(indexPath.row)
    {
    case 1:

        break

    case 2:

        break

    case 3 :
    break

        .
        .
        .
    case 15 :
     break
    default :
        print( "default case")

    }
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks In Advance...

Comment: I think if you're having to do that, your overall logic is wack. Try encapsulating whatever you're having 15 cases for, into (a) new class(es).

Comment: associated UIViewController  are the same for everything  or different on each case

Comment: Try to use storyboard Id as 0,1,2 ... for your 15 storyboards. And on item select fetch that viewController using self.storyboard.instantiateViewControlerWithIdentifier

Comment: What do you do in each of the 15 cases?

Comment: are you there if you wont reply , we can't help

Comment: I am using different UIViewControllers for each case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the view controller's `Identifier` to an array. On click on cell, get the identifier from array and push the particular view controller.

```
    let arrayTest : NSArray = ["test1", "test2"]// Declared this on view did load

//Write below code on did select delegate method
    let identifier = arrayTest.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    let viewController = UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: It is showing dis error "Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> UIViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'" . If i change the code like this "  let identifier = arrayTest.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        let viewController = UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier as! UIStoryboard)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
"

Comment: Try the following woring code:-
let arrayTest : NSArray = ["test1", "test2"]// Declared this on view did load

        let identifier : String = arrayTest.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)  as! ViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

Comment: It is crashing.It shows the error "Could not cast value of type 'Sales.OrderViewController' (0x14e578) to 'Sales.ViewController."

Comment: Make viewController as OrderViewController. Update the following line:-  let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! OrderViewController

Comment: I have different viewcontroller with different names.If i click on first row,it will navigate to that orderviewcontroller. 2nd row some different ViewController...

Comment: If associated viewcontrollers are different then don't cast them. Update the following line:- let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120675/discussion-between-pkc456-and-anusha-hrithi).